# How to return a simple int value in C# Console App

Tags: c#, methods, int, return

OK, so I couldn't find anything as remedial on this website, started programming about three days ago and i'm working through this book. I'm practicing methods on my own I cannot get my int method to return the product of a simple expression in my Main method.

Here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(test(5, 5));

        }

        static int test(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int hold = num1 * num2;
            Console.ReadLine();
            return hold;
        }
    }
  }
```

Any extra info would on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. I'm certain it is an end user logic error.

Comment: The `ReadLine` will wait until you enter a line (by pressing enter) before it can continue.

Comment: Use Console.Readline() or Console.ReadKey() or run your app using ctrl+f5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`Console.ReadLine()` is used to get Input from Keyboard

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(test(5, 5));
           Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int test(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int hold = num1 * num2;

            return hold;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something dumb.

Answer (score 3):

You *just* need to delete `Console.ReadLine` line in your method.

It expects to enter a string from console. Since you provide your parameter as `(5, 5)`, this line is unnecessary.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test(5, 5)); // Prints 25
}
static int test(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code little bit like below. It will works.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(test(5, 5));

        }

        static int test(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int hold = num1 * num2;
            Console.ReadLine();
            return hold;
        }
    }
  }
```